# When $f(x)=ax+b$ intersects with $h(x)=cx+d$

Tags: functions

I got two functions that draw dots in one dimension, the first one starts with $b$, and then draws a dot every $a$. And the second one starts with $d$ and then draws a dot every $c$.

I figure that I have two functions $f(x)=ax+b$ and $h(x)=cx+d$, and what I need to do is just to compare them, so I am getting $cx+d=ax+b$. However, that gives me just one solution while in practice they will intersect at list once every $ac$ cycle. How can I find all their intersection points?

Comment: It's not the same $x$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh, ok. What I really want then is to find when $f(x)=h(x)$ for the same $x$ value. How can I do that?

Comment: If I understand what you are saying (not clear), you might be better off thinking of these as two arithmetic progressions, $\{an+b\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $\{cm+d\}_{m=0}^{\infty}$.  These intersect any time there are integers $(n,m)$ such that $an+b=cm+d$.  Depending on the parameters $a,b,c,d$ these may never intersect.  But if we have a single intersection $an_0+ b=cm_0+d$ then they intersect again at  $a(n_0+ct)+b=c(m_0+at)+d$ for every natural number $t$.

Comment: @lulu yeah this is what I want. So how do I find this first intersection, assuming there is one. Also, in my case $n,m$ are distinct primes, not sure if this info helps.

Comment: In my notation, $n$ and $m$ are variables.  It doesn't make sense to say that they are "distinct primes.".  As to how to find the intersection, if there is one, that's what the Chinese Remainder Theorem is for.  You want to solve $N\equiv b\pmod a$ and $N\equiv d \pmod c$ simultaneously.  This will always be possible if $\gcd (a,c)=1$ and it will sometimes be possible if the gcd is $>1$, but in the latter case it will sometimes not be possible.

Comment: Are you familiar with Bezout’s identity?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner no, going to check it out

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using a Chinese reminder with an extended Euclidean algorithm. I searched for a value $v$ that is equal to $b,d$ mod $a,c$. Then the collision function is $F(x)=v + acx$

Comment: when you said equalitarian, did you mean Euclidean?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yeah sorry, Grammarly got leggy. Fixed it now.